# What is $\sum_{k=1}^n{{n}\choose{k}}k^{3}$ equal to?

Tags: combinatorics, summation

Find a compact form for the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^n{{n}\choose{k}}k^{3}$$

I have been trying to solve this question for some time now. My guess is that I am supposed to write this in terms of something simpler (like a power of a simple sum) but I just can't come up with anything. I would appreciate it if you could give me a hint before providing the full answer so I can think about it on my own.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to do $ \sum {n \choose k }$ or $ \sum{n\choose k } k $?

Comment: General tip: try computing a few terms, then searching on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/). I put in $6$ terms, and it came up with the correct sequence as the top result.

Comment: I've posted a different approach at the duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the simpler sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} kx^k = x\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} kx^{k-1} = x\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k\right)' = x((1+x)^n)'$$

(The sums can start at $0$ or $1$ since the $0$th term is $0$, but start at $0$ to make life easier). Now how would you do the $k^3$ case instead?

Comment: I wrote the binomial expansion for $(1+x)^n$, took its derivative and then multiplied it by x and then plugged in 1 to get the sum for the $k^1$ case. Then I did the same thing 2 more times and plugged in 1 to get the sum for the $k^3$ case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**    Prove the following

1.$\sum { n \choose k } k =  n \sum { n - 1 \choose k - 1 } $.
2. $ \sum { n \choose k } k (k-1) = n (n-1) \sum { n - 2 \choose k - 2 }$.
3. A similar identity.